# Aligning items inside of the flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I can't figure it out. If I have something like this:

```css
html,body,div {margin:0;padding:0;}
.cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
}
.one, .two, .three {width: 150px;}
.one {
  background: #009;
}
.two {
  background: #090;
}
.three {

  background: #900;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">

  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>

</div>
```

Then, how would I change the `.two`, so it would be exactly after the `.one` without spacing? The `self-align` didn't work for me, for some reason.

- It's about flex, of course. Not aligning it at all cost.
- I want to be able to change **only** the `.two`, without touching the other elements.

Is this possible using flex?

Comment: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @AjAX. why would you point me at something I can find in a second in google? ...omfg

Comment: This is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adjust the margin of the `.two`:

```css
html,
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  /* removed this
  justify-content: space-between;*/
}

.one,
.two,
.three {
  width: 150px;
}

.one {
  background: #009;
}

.two {
  background: #090;
  margin-right: auto; /*added this*/
}

.three {
  background: #900;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">

  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Daaaaamn, man! wtf... :) Can you explain it, please? Why is the margin doing it?

Comment: @moviluxeg this is the magic of flexbox ;) margin:auto is used to align items and to also distribute the free spacing. By adding marign-right:auto to 2 or margin-left:auto to 3 you make the margin take all the free spacing https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins

Comment: @moviluxeg here is a good article to understand : https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-how-z-index-and-auto-margins-work-in-flexbox/

Comment: damn maaaaan, you're awesome! :)